# Why am I getting an unexpected token in my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have one problem which I can't really figure out how to fix it. I've checked the React documentation and my syntax is like in the one in the official documentation from Facebook.

I've just started learning React library, learned how to use props but with state I have a problem. This code throws an error which says that the comma character doesn't belong there while in the documentation the comma is present. If I remove the comma, then it says `todos is undefined`:

```
class App extends Component {
  // State
  getInitialState() {
      return (
        todos: ["Wake up early", "Do some body exercise", "Continue learning React"]
      )
  }, <-- This is making the problem and it can't compile 
  // Props
  render () {
    return (
      <div id ="todo-list">
       <h1>Helo, user</h1>
       <p>Things to do:</p>
       <ul>
        <li>{this.state.todos[0]}</li>
        <li>{this.state.todos[1]}</li>
        <li>{this.state.todos[2]}</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I'm learning from this tutorial [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKOyhW754hA), followed his tutorials so far, but I came across this error and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to use ES5 syntax to create your component, in an ES2015 class, which doesn't work out. There are some key differences when using ES2015 classes to define your components.

Inside ES2015 classes, there are no commas between methods, you may be getting that confused with object literals.

Also, in ES2015 classes, you must use the `constructor` to set initial state, not `getInitialState`. That's for ES5's `createClass`. The constructor is called when a new instance of the component is created and "constructs the component", acting like the `componentWillMount` method. It's a "reserved" method in ES2015 classes. Here's how to use the `constructor`:

```
constructor() {
    super(); //super before anything else to call superclass constructor
    this.state = {
        todos: ["Wake up early", "Do some body exercise", "Continue learning React"]
    };
}
```

This will set the `this.state` object directly (only ever do this in the constructor!) The reason why `todos` was undefined was because React with ES2015 doesn't use `getInitialState` as it did in ES5. Thus, you never really set the state and `todos` is undefined.

Notes: Don't use IDs in React components. React components are meant to be *reusable*, and if you can't have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer did help me understand the error. Your code did fixed my problem, but I had to add "super()" before "this.state" because it threw another error " "this" is not allowed before super()". Then of course, copied that error into Google and found the solution on GitHub issue, where I only needed to add "super()" method after " constructor()" and before "this.state". Thanks again for your quick answer and for teaching me how to use JS and React more properly. Thank you Andrew, kudos! :)

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Oh yes. I forgot that. Always use `super` to call the superclass constructor, which is `Component`. Also, do not use IDs with components, because you can't have duplicate IDs.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, about the ID's. I will use "className" instead. I've totally forgot that I'm learning a library that reuses components. Thanks again I guess.